Folks, please upvote questions, too!
I have noticed for quiet some time now that the poster of an answer can have three or more upvotes, but the asker gets none whatsoever.
I think this is discouraging for those asking the questions and we should upvote legit questions, especially when they show that the asker has researched the topic before sitting down to ask the question.

I often forget about it. When I read the answers, and scroll down, it happens frequentl that I should upvote the question as well, if it is a good one. Somehow it feels more natural to upvote answers than upvoting questions.

@Devolus: probably because one thinks that the asker hasn't put any effort into it. Often it's quite to the contrary. Also, these Q&A pages wouldn't be anything without questions, because there would be no questions to answer ;)
